# Excel formatting seconds and minutes/time?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have values displayed as 29.87, which is 29.87 seconds in from my POV, Sometimes I have minutes entered as 1:09.89, meaning 1 minute, 9 seconds, etc.

My main question is can I work a formula to add something like 29.87 with 40.02 so it displays as 1:09.89 after adding the two numbers from the cells? Currently, it displays as 69.89 when added, and no other display option I have tried have it correctly displayed how I want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula : `=TEXT((A1+B1)/(24*60*60),"HH:mm.00")`

[image]